# REGEX: Find the html tags that contain an operator, but which do not contain other operator

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

```
1. <p class="mb-40px">My nick name is Prince and <a href="https://mywebsite.com/bla.html" class="color-gege" target="_new">my real name</a> is beyond magic.</p>
    
2. <p class="mb-40px">I love my home s< because I stay with my lovely cat.</p>

3. <p class="mb-40px">Because of this book t< I cannot sleep well.</p>
```

I want to find only the lines that have the operator **<** included in the html tag `<p class="mb-40px"> </p>` , except those lines that have

In my example above, the output should be line 2 (that have  **s<** ) and line 3 ( that have **t<** )

So, I use an old generic formula: `(REGION-START)+(.)+\K(FIND REGEX)(?s:(?=.*(REGION-FINAL)))`

In my case FIND: `(<p class="mb-40px">)+(.)+\K(\w<)(?s:(?=.*(</p>)))`

The problem is that my regex find also the `e</a>` from the first line. And I don't wanna find the tags with `</a>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:(?!</p>).)*< .*?</p>`
- Replace with: `\u$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">     # literally
(?:(?!</p>).)*          # Tempered Greedy Token
                        # make sure we don't encountered </p>
<                       # < and a space
.*?                     # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</p>                    # literally
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: ok, but if I want to find the same tags, but only the one that does't have the word `home` ?

Comment: @JustMe: Add `(?!home)` or better `(?!\bhome\b)` in the Tempered Greedy Token: `(?:(?!</p>)(?!\bhome\b).)*`

Comment: Wonderful: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:(?!</p>)(?!\bhome\b).)*</p>`  Thanks @Toto

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

FIND: `(?<p class="mb-40px"><(?!/a)[^>]*</p>)`

Comment: What are you trying to match with `(?<p...`? `(?<` [is not valid in regex](https://regex101.com/r/naoPPM/1)

Comment: but it is working...

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't, have you seen the link provided in my previous comment?